# TabContainer throws error when it is in updatepanel in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, pagerequestmanager

I have an AJAX `Tabcontainer` in update panel. The `tabcontainer` has menus which redirects to other page. when I click on other tab it wont switch and remains on same tab and throws error.

[image]

Not able to find out the Error source any idea?
How to get the error line number/ any method to resolve this issue?

Help appreciated!

Comment: Do you have `ScriptManager` placed in the page or master page ?

Comment: yes its on master page!

Comment: Try replacing that with `<asp:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server"/>` and see if it works.